# How to set different color or background for a cell that changes on dark mode?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have tried searching but have not found the answer. I hope somebody has a solution.

My Cell with an `A` font color is `black` and the background color is `yellow`, it's good looking on a **Desktop with a light theme** but when I am using in Sheet app on **Android** with **View in dark theme** mode, it's not good looking as looking font color is `white` and background is `yellow`.

```
function myFn() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange('A1');
  range.setFontColor("black").setBackground("yellow");
  //Looking rest conditions..
};
```

Comment: Google script won't know if it's dark mode or light mode so it's going to be the same as it is for web designers: design your sheet to work well with both or switch the android app to light mode as well. I'd suggest using something other than black so it does not change to white. Dark Grey 3 looks like it would work fine. Still fairly dark in light mode and readable in dark mode with yellow background. Or you can change the background

Comment: Do you mean the Dark Grey 3 needs to use on android device or it's available specially for google sheets?

Comment: Apply the Dark Grey 3 in the Google Sheet cell that is currently black. Take in consideration that even if Google Apps Script had a way to know the file is being open in Android Dark mode, and trigger the change of color. It will update the color for all the users that have access to the sheet, not just the one in the android device. So I agree with @Vytautas that your best option is to use a different color for the cell.

Comment: Maybe you can add a feature request by following the steps in this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support#developer_product_feedback)